# DataFormWebPart and wierd exception

Tags: xslt, data-form-web-part

I have web page with four DataFormWebParts that are presenting data from SPList. DataFormWebPart layupt is defined with Xslt. On SharePoint 2007 everything works correctly. When I migrated site collection to SharePoint 2010 I'm getting exception when trying open this web page:

```
Leaving Monitored Scope (PostResolveRequestCacheHandler). Execution Time=65.5818087918797

Setting [Display] as the FormContext.FormMode for the current page

System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.   
 at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)    
 at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)    
 at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.ApplyReceivedFilterData()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.ApplyReceivedConsumerData()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetRowData(RowCallback callback)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.IWebPartRow.GetRowData(RowCallback callback)    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.RowToParametersTransformer.System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.IWebPartParameters.GetParametersData(ParametersCallback callback)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.SetConnectedFilterProvider(IWebPartParameters provider)

 Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://testsite:28242/Call_View.aspx)). Execution Time=884.231867252101
```

What can be the reason? Why the same code is working on SP 2007 but not on SP 2010? Any Ideas?

EDIT:
I have found that SPProxyWebPartmanager is causing those issues. In proxy manager, there are defined four connections.

```
<WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager runat="server" id="ProxyWebPartManager">
        <SPWebPartConnections>
            <WebPartPages:spwebpartconnection ID="g_634314CC6BF14016AF2F5CCB2965E109" ConsumerConnectionPointID="DFWP Filter Consumer ID" ConsumerID="g_65f1888f_8c82_47a0_a0f4_811fb86cbe02" ProviderConnectionPointID="DFWP Row Provider ID" ProviderID="g_31ffab7b_352c_48a8_8ab2_4582ba3b77c4">
                <asp:rowtoparameterstransformer ProviderFieldNames="@PVID" ConsumerFieldNames="@PVID" />
            </WebPartPages:spwebpartconnection>

            <WebPartPages:spwebpartconnection ID="g_B00F4A5DDB6B46FDB8DF7512AB475309" ConsumerConnectionPointID="DFWP Filter Consumer ID" ConsumerID="g_57d2b574_f665_46bf_95d8_101827f47b09" ProviderConnectionPointID="DFWP Row Provider ID" ProviderID="g_31ffab7b_352c_48a8_8ab2_4582ba3b77c4">
                    <asp:rowtoparameterstransformer ProviderFieldNames="@PVID" ConsumerFieldNames="@PVID" />
            </WebPartPages:spwebpartconnection>

            <WebPartPages:spwebpartconnection ID="g_2020BFAFDB0E4CD78F1978957E14939A" ConsumerConnectionPointID="DFWP Filter Consumer ID" ConsumerID="g_65f1888f_8c82_47a0_a0f4_811fb86cbe02" ProviderConnectionPointID="DFWP Row Provider ID" ProviderID="g_44635300_77d9_4af4_95b8_0d8923be45bb">
                    <asp:rowtoparameterstransformer ProviderFieldNames="@PVID" ConsumerFieldNames="@PVID" />
            </WebPartPages:spwebpartconnection>

            <WebPartPages:spwebpartconnection ID="g_8FB11979EF1A46FB9246DEB083B1E288" ConsumerConnectionPointID="DFWP Filter Consumer ID" ConsumerID="g_57d2b574_f665_46bf_95d8_101827f47b09" ProviderConnectionPointID="DFWP Row Provider ID" ProviderID="g_44635300_77d9_4af4_95b8_0d8923be45bb">
                    <asp:rowtoparameterstransformer ProviderFieldNames="@PVID" ConsumerFieldNames="@PVID" />
            </WebPartPages:spwebpartconnection>
        </SPWebPartConnections>
    </WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>
```

When I removed SPProxyWebPArtManager everything works correctly.
Why SPProxyWebPartManager is cousing issues on SP 2010?